# what is the difference between these two exection commands in c#

Tags: executequery

Do you know the difference between these two conditions?

1

```
if(reader.hasrows())
{
   while(reader.read())
   {

   }
}
```

2

```
while(reader.read())
{
   if(reader.hasrows())
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing if/while or while/if is not necessary, since "while(reader.read())" will only return true when the reader has rows "hasrows()" and has a row to read "read()".  The extra nesting has no value.

Comment: I'm assume your using something that implements IDataReader, here is the MSDN link for the Read() method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read.aspx, notice how it say's that read() only return true it it has "more" rows to read...